# Function overload with C++ using VS2017

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-2017, overloading, codeblocks

I'm having a problem compiling this simple code in VS2017, but the code is working fine in Code Blocks.
In VS2017 I've got this error message:

> C2382 'abs':redefinition; different exception specifications

Here is the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int abs(int i);
float abs(float f);

int main()
{
    cout << abs(-10) << endl;
    cout << abs(-11.0f) << endl;
    return 0;
}
int abs(int i)
{
    cout << "Using integer abs()\n";
    return i<0 ? -i : i;
}
float abs(float f)
{
    cout << "Using float abs()\n";
    return f<0.0f ? -f : f;
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a library function yourself instead of including the appropriate header?

Comment: Probably because the name `abs` is already taken.

Comment: There's an `abs` function in the standard library. `using namespace std` is causing the problem, but you shouldn't use the name `abs` in the global namespace anyway to avoid conflict with C

Comment: See [`std::abs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs).

Comment: Also see [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is because there are already a set of functions called `abs` in the standard library, which would normally have to be accessed with `std::`, but `using namespace std` removes that qualifier, creating a name collision between all the functions. Thus, you should either change the name of your functions to something like `myAbs`, or remove the `using namespace std`. An even better change would be to both remove the `using` statement *and* rename the function.

Your code exhibits a key reason to why `using namespace std` should be avoided, since it can cause namespace collisions and unnecessary confusion.